# Background processing gives me BAD ACCESS crash?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, background-process

I followed this guide here to doing background processing:

http://evilrockhopper.com/2010/01/iphone-development-keeping-the-ui-responsive-and-a-background-thread-pattern/

And the only 1 line of code which was put to background processing was:

sound = flite_text_to_wave([cleanString UTF8String], voice);

But for some reason i got a bad access signal.

Debugging it shows that it crashes on that line too. This is the code I now have in that part. Bear in mind that most of this is just default Flite stuff from the sfoster project which has had no problems before, when it was all together, not separated into 3.

```
-(void)speakText:(NSString *)text //This is called by my app
{

    cleanString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
    if([text length] > 1)
    {
        int x = 0;
        while (x < [text length])
        {
            unichar ch = [text characterAtIndex:x];
            [cleanString appendFormat:@"%c", ch];
            x++;
        }
    }
    if(cleanString == nil)
    {   // string is empty
        cleanString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
    }
    //The next line i've put in from the link
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundTextToSpeech) withObject:nil];

}

-(void)backgroundTextToSpeech {
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
//The following line is the one it crashes on
    sound = flite_text_to_wave([cleanString UTF8String], voice);
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(backToForegroundTextToSpeech) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    [pool release];
}


-(void)backToForegroundTextToSpeech {

    NSArray *filePaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *recordingDirectory = [filePaths objectAtIndex: 0];
    // Pick a file name
    tempFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%s", recordingDirectory, "temp.wav"];
    // save wave to disk
    char *path; 
    path = (char*)[tempFilePath UTF8String];
    cst_wave_save_riff(sound, path);
    // Play the sound back.
    NSError *err;
    [audioPlayer stop];
    audioPlayer =  [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempFilePath] error:&err];
    [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];


}
```

Any ideas what i've done wrong/what i can do differently to stop this happening?

EDIT: A picture of the debugger after changing it round with some code posted below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don’t understand how autoreleasing works. You assign the `cleanString` variable an autoreleased object and then start some processing on background that uses this value. But when the method that started the background processing returns the control to the main run loop, the autoreleased string stored in the `cleanString` gets deallocated and the background thread runs into a zombie.

You could simplify the code using [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html):

```
- (void) startProcessing {
    NSString *source = [NSString stringWithWhatever…];
    dispatch_queue_t targetQ = 
        dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(targetQ, ^{
        sound = flite_text_to_wave…;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self speechProcessingDone];
        });
    });
}
```

The advantages are that you don’t have to maintain your own autorelease pool, you don’t have to add extra methods just to have one line executed in background *and* the block will retain your string, so that you won’t crash.

But you should certainly not use GCD just to get around the autoreleasing issue without knowing what’s happening. Memory management is the base, you must be 100% sure what you are doing.

---

If this is above your head, make sure you know how memory management works in Cocoa, for example by reading this [Objective-C tutorial by Scott Stevenson](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/). You *have* to do this, there is no way around.

Then come back to the code and you will see that the mutable strings that you store into `cleanString` are autoreleased, meaning they will get deallocated sometime soon after you leave the current function. After running the selector in background, you exit the current function and the string stored in `cleanString` gets deallocated. Soon after that the background thread gets to the following line:

```
sound = flite_text_to_wave([cleanString UTF8String], voice);
```

But as the object stored in `cleanString` was already deallocated, you get the crash. The solution is simply to retain the object until you are done with it. You can retain it before running the background thread and release when the background thread ends.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. As i said most of that code is imported from flite, the only bit of releasing i did was with the pool, and for that i followed it exactly as the guide on the link i posted showed.

Answer (score 1):

first thing that jumps out:

your class needs to hold a retain count for `cleanString`.

typically, this is accomplished via a retained (or copied, which is generally preferable with NSStrings and other concrete/immutable types) property:

```
@interface MONSpeaker : NSObject
{
    NSString * cleanString;
}

@property (copy) NSString * cleanString;

@end

@implementation MONSpeaker

@synthesize cleanString;

/* ... */

- (void)dealloc
{
  [cleanString release], cleanString = nil;
  [super dealloc];
}

-(void)speakText:(NSString *)text // This is called by my app
{

    NSMutableString * str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
    if([text length] > 1)
    {
        int x = 0;
        while (x < [text length])
        {
            unichar ch = [text characterAtIndex:x];
            [str appendFormat:@"%c", ch];
            x++;
        }
    }
    if(str == nil) // why not check for nil at creation instead?
    { // string is empty
        str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
    }
    self.cleanString = str;
    // The next line i've put in from the link
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundTextToSpeech) withObject:nil];

}

-(void)backgroundTextToSpeech {
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
// The following line is the one it crashes on
    sound = flite_text_to_wave([self.cleanString UTF8String], voice);
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(backToForegroundTextToSpeech) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    [pool release];
}

@end
```

ok - so this isn't 100% thread-safe, but it is idiomatic.

the variant which is more resistant to threading issues would pass the string as an argument to `backgroundTextToSpeech:(NSString *)text`. `backgroundTextToSpeech:(NSString *)text` would then create a copy of the argument `text` (and of course release the copy before `pool` is destroyed).

Comment: Nope, i pasted this in but it crashed again.

Comment: Man, you can’t just paste pieces of code from the web and hope the result works :) You have to undestand what you are doing. I’ll try to expand my answer.

Comment: i just reread the implementation i updated, it looks fine. why is the app crashing? is it crashing for a different reason since updating? the part i rewrote solved one issue, but there could be others. have you tried running with NSZombies enabled? if there is an objc memory management issue - NSZombies may help isolate the object.

Comment: I posted a screenshot above. NSZombies is enabled, but all that appears in the debugger is: `2011-02-02 09:29:49.509 Alarms[10794:7f07] *** -[CFString UTF8String]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5ce2400`. I'm unsure how to fix this? I get the line it's referring to, but i don't know how to fix it?

Comment: ok - this means a string's over-released. the sample i posted still looks fine =) triple-check your implementation: where else do you access `cleanString`? triple-check that you've copied the code i posted correctly. you can also test the string, to ensure you're looking in the right places. at `self.cleanString = str;` add
`[self.cleanString retain];` -- this will introduce a leak, but your program will not (usually) crash in the same way if this is the problem. you'll obviously need to remove the introduced leak once the problem's located.

Comment: Ok, i re-copied in the code. The problem from before isn't there now. So i took the ` [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(backToForegroundTextToSpeech) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];` line out of the code because that was giving me an error of `'-[FliteTTS backToForegroundTextToSpeech]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xae781e0'` now that is no longer there. Now it works fine on the simulator but on my iPod Touch it runs up to this line.. `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundTextToSpeech) withObject:nil];` and then gives me a bad access error.

Comment: My iPod Touch is 1st gen so running iOS 3.1.3. Maybe that's the problem here? It just seems bizarre that in the simulator that runs without a hitch, and on the iPod Touch it has a bad access error. Any ideas? It's this line thats the problem now, to be clear. `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundTextToSpeech) withObject:nil];`. Giving me bad access.

Comment: that's great that it solved the problem. based on the 'odd' errors you're seeing, you probably have more memory errors. your class uses a few more instance variables... they do not look like they are managed correctly - they are just assigned autoreleased objects. so you have to fix those, using `@property (retain)` or `@property (copy)`. it's not odd that you see different results in the sim since you're working with multithreading on different hardware. first implement and use your properties correctly, then retest with NSZombies enabled.

Comment: also, you can implement speakText as `-(void)speakText:(NSString *)text { self.cleanString = text ? text : @""; [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundTextToSpeech) withObject:nil]; }
`

Comment: lastly, multithreaded programs can be very difficult to test and debug in some cases. make sure you have a firm understanding of memory management before complicating your program with multithreading. use the leaks tool to ensure you don't have leaks (the effect of under-releasing). good luck

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. I thought i had everything down. I can't see any more problems in it. And about the text thing.. i know, it was like that originally but when i broke it up into parts i needed to set it as a string for it to work.

Comment: ok, you'll have to read through apple's memory management guide and learn. in almost every case, you'll want to use properties to access and set instance variables. so all of your class variables which are objc objects should be converted to an implementation requiring changes similar to the ones i made for cleanString. the example you posted shows multiple additional variables, as well as other issues, such as leaks. (one variation of) Leaks is a template found in Instruments.app. every objc dev should know how to manage memory in Cocoa. good luck